# How to hide options in crystal report file format dialogue

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report in visual studio 2012 asp.net c#.I want to hide some options from crystal report dialogue because it is not working correctly.Option are following

```
1- Microsoft Word (97-2003)Data Only
2-Microsoft  Excel (97-2003)Data Only
3-XML
```

etc...
How can i hide these options from crystal report.

Answer (score 1):

We need to assign an OnLoad event handler to the ReportViewer control as shown below.

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1"
                runat="server"
                Width="600"
                OnLoad="ReportViewer_OnLoad">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Then inside the event handler we will write code to hide the Export option in the export button DropDown.

All the export options in ReportViewer control are available through the ListRenderingExtentionsList method. From this list we need to find the extension of the Export option we wish to hide, thus I have done that by matching the extension name in the Lambda expression query.

Once the extension is found we need to access its `m_isVisible` property using Reflection and set it to false.

```
protected void ReportViewer_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string exportOption = "Excel";
    //string exportOption = "Word";
    //string exportOption = "XML";
    RenderingExtension extension = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions().ToList().Find(x => x.Name.Equals(exportOption,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (extension != null)
    {
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        fieldInfo.SetValue(extension, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this viwer <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer"  runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" OnLoad="ReportViewer_OnLoad"  />

Comment: RenderingExtension extension = CrystalReportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions().ToList().Find(x => x.Name.Equals(exportOption,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

Comment: Local report and ListRenderingExtensions is not exist.How can i get extension